# Find nested User Control

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control within a user control.  I want to reference the nested user control from the code-behind of a page using user control #1.  And user control#1 has nested usercontrol #1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call it from the page itself, so you'll have to expose the nested user control in the user control itself.

```
public Control NestedUserControl
{
  get{ return FindControl(nameOfUserControl);}
}
```

And in the code behind of the page just do:

```
UserControl1.NestedUserControl
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the FindControl method.

```
UseControl1.FindControl("IdOfNestedUserControl");
```